# Unexpected exception when invoking webpack from gulp

Tags: typescript, webpack, gulp

I have successfully configured webpack to bundle together my TypeScript sources. I basically followed [these instructions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) from the TypeScript project.

As a result, when I type `npx webpack`, I get:

```
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using typescript@2.9.2 from typescript
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from frontend/tsconfig.json
ℹ ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
ℹ ｢atl｣: Time: 744ms
Hash: 6577bf320859d1e9dabb
Version: webpack 4.12.2
Time: 2060ms
Built at: 06/27/2018 9:02:28 PM
        Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  1.39 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  5.43 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
[0] external "React" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[2] external "ReactDOM" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[3] ./src/index.tsx 326 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden module
```

Great. Now I want to make a Gulp task that runs this to generate my bundled `.js` file. My barebones `gulpfile.babel.js` looks like this. I'm using webpack-stream to allow me to pipe through webpack.

```
import gulp from 'gulp'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import webpackStream from 'webpack-stream'
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.js'


gulp.task('js', () => {
  gulp.src('./src/index.tsx')
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig), webpack)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
})
```

When I run `npx gulp js`, it spews out:

```
[21:03:57] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[21:03:57] Requiring external module babel-register
[21:03:58] Using gulpfile frontend/gulpfile.babel.js
[21:03:58] Starting 'js'...
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using typescript@2.9.2 from typescript
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from frontend/tsconfig.json
Error: It looks like you're using an old webpack version without hooks support. If you're using awesome-script-loader with React storybooks consider upgrading @storybook/react to at least version 4.0.0-alpha.3
    at Object.ensureInstance (frontend/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/instance.ts:142:9)
```

I'm stumped as to why it would behave differently with this seemingly minor change. If indeed an older version of webpack is being loaded, where is it coming from?

Here are the dependencies declared in package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "webpack": "^4.12.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-stream": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.4.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  }
```

The versions of `typescript`, `webpack`, `webpack-cli` declared by `awesome-typescript-loader` are the same major.minor as my package.json declares. However, `webpack-stream` maybe is older, as it references webpack 3.4.1 (currently 4.12.2) and gulp 3.9.0 (currently 4.0.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the culprit was webpack-stream using an old version of webpack; it hasn't been updated yet to support webpack 4. There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream/pull/188) which resolves the issue for me but it has not yet been accepted.

Others have commented that it should be resolved by passing in the newer webpack module, but I *did*, here, and it did not seem to do anything.

```
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig), webpack)
```